# The name 'PermissionsImplementation' does not exist in the current context

Tags: xamarin

This problem popped up in my Xamarin project when I updated my visual studio. So I created a new [Blank] Xamarin test project to see if it exists with nothing else going on.

I installed the Plugin.Permissions using Nuget. Then added the code as specified by https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/PermissionsPlugin

My MainActivity.cs now looks like:

```
using System;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;

namespace TestApp1.Droid
{
    [Activity(Label = "TestApp1", Icon = "@mipmap/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            Plugin.CurrentActivity.CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            LoadApplication(new App());
        }

        public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults) {
          PermissionsImplementation.Current.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
          base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
  }

}
```

And I get the compiler error: "The name 'PermissionsImplementation' does not exist in the current context"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add

```
using Plugin.Permissions;
```

Comment: Oh, no. It works in the sample project I made. But it doesn't work in the actual project. I wonder why?

Comment: is the plugin installed in both the shared and platform projects?

Comment: That's strange. Nuget isn't showing a shared project option for any of the plugins in that project. Just Android and iOS.

Comment: I shut down visual studio then went and deleted the 'packages' folders and then the 'bin' and 'obj' folders  in the Android directory. Restarted the IDE and that finally resolved the issue.